# How to loop over nested array in vue and display data every 5 seconds?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, settimeout, v-for

I'm using Vue Js and I have a nested array like this:

```
    arrays: [
      {
         name: 'Max',
         Info: [60, 75, 70, 85, 65], 
      },
      {
         name: 'Dave,
         Info: [70, 95, 60, 65, 83], 
      },
     ]
```

I have a user profile box that displays name and info for each user.

```
<div class="outer"  v-for="(item, index) in arrays" :key="item.id" v-bind:id="item.name">
```

I would like to display info in template:

```
<div class="box c" >Info<span v-for="info in item.Info">{{info}}</span></div>
```

When I did this it showed the correct array for the correct user but it displayed all numbers
but **I would like info to show each number only for 5 seconds until the last number**. So for Max it will display 60 then wait 5 seconds, then will only show 75 wait 5 seconds etc until it stops at the last number and only displays that number.

I tried creating a function :

```
  appendInfo: function() {
    
 for (let i = 0, l = this.arrays.length; i < l; i++) {
    let info = this.arrays[i]['Info'];
 
    
 let timer = 0;
   
    for (let i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => this.rate = info[i], timer);
      timer = timer + 5000;
      
  }
    
}
```

and passed data to rate

```
return {
      count: null, 
      rate: [],
```

and used {{rate}} in the template

```
<div class="box c" >Info<span>{{rate}}</span></div>
```

but it only displayed data from the second user profile for both profiles.

So I'm wondering if there is either a way to do this with v-for or how I can modify my function?
Thanks!

## Update

I used the RateDisplayer component like so:

```
<div class="outer"  v-for="(item, index) in arrays" :key="item.id" v-bind:id="item.name">
  <rate-displayer :rates="item.Info" />

import RateDisplayer from './RateDisplayer'
export default {
  name: 'card',
  props: {
            rates: {
                required: true,
            }
        
        },
  data () {
    return {
      interval: 5000,
      rate: false,
...
```

but still displayed only last arrays values.

## Fixed

I removed from parent component:

```
props: {
            rates: {
                required: true,
            }

        },
 
      interval: 5000,
      rate: false,
```

and now it's working, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like that before. First, I suggest you to create a component JUST for this part:

```
<div class="box c" >Info<span>{{rate}}</span></div>
```

then, in this component you can accept rates as prop, and set rate every 5 sec to the new one. Something like:

```
<template>
    <div class="box c" v-if="rate">Info<span>{{rate}}</span></div>
</template>

 export default {

   name: "RateDisplayer.vue",
        props: {
            rates: {
                required: true,
            }
        
        },
        data() {
            return {
                interval: 5000,
                rate: false
            }
        },
    mounted(){ this.nextOrStop(-1) },
    methods: { 
      nextOrStop(current)
      {
         if(current === this.rates.length-1) {  return }
         setTimeout( () => {
             const index = current+1;
             this.rate = this.rates[index];
             this.nextOrStop(index)
             }, this.interval)

    }

  ....
```

### You can insert this component inside your parent component like this:

```
<div class="outer"  
     v-for="(item, index) in arrays" 
    :key="item.id" 
     v-bind:id="item.name">

         <rate-displayer :rates="item.Info" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much this is very useful! I'm still having a problem though with it only displaying info from the last array. It shows each number every 5 seconds but only the numbers from the last array for every user. Is there a way I can display each users correct array values?

Comment: I just changed the answer to include how you should use the new component inside your parent component.

Comment: Thank you! Still seems to be displaying only the last array's numbers though.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Can you paste in your original answer an **update** with how you're using this component? 
The behavior that you describe usually it happens on not named components.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated with how I'm using the component.